# Does anyone know the time that the app review process closes?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I originally thought they review from 9-5pm, however my app was rejected at 7:51pm... Are they reviewing them 24/7 or do they close at a certain time. (I'm in the same time zone as cupertino)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

24/7 Whenever they get around to checking yours out. 
Normally it takes 10-15 days to get an app on the app store.

Comment: I've had the average be pretty consistently seven days for a while now...  But I agree they are reviewing 24/7.

Comment: Well with 500,000 jobs created you got time to spare ;)

Comment: kk, because mine went back into review at 6:02 pm, and I was wondering wether they will finish reviewing it tonight or would it go into tomorrow.